# Having an issue with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

Hi I've not that long started programming in c++ but have a few years experience in other languages. At the moment I'm working on a basic game where the player will fight their monsters against AI monsters in a final fantasy style game.

the champion class inherits from an AbstractMonster class and i want the player to be able to select their starting monster from a selection. However at the moment i only have the one programmed as if i can get this to work i should be able to get the rest

The problem I'm having is with a pointer to the player monster as it keeps bringing up a. Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

This is the only parts of the header file that i'm using at the moment

```
#include "AbstractMonster.h"
#include "Champion.h"

class mainGame{
public:
    void createMonster()
private:    
    AbstractMonster* playerMonster = nullptr;
}
```

The function within the .cpp file is the following

```
void mainGame::createMonster(){    
    playerMonster = new Champion(); //this is the line the errors at and it highlights playerMonster  
}
```

any help will be much appreciated as i have had this problem for a couple of days now.

Comment: So where do you allocate memory if input != 1 ?

Comment: Not enough code to determine problem.

Comment: You probably have a null pointer somewhere, i.e. a pointer that doesn't point to an object, which can happen when your input above is not 1.

Comment: What do the Champion & Shaman header files look like?  Do they both inherit from AbstractMonster?

Comment: The error sounds like a null pointer.

Comment: sorry. forgot to say that the champion and shaman inherit from an absractMonster class

Comment: Hi guys, what code do you need to see to be able to get an idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Access violation writing location 0x00000000.` Tells me that you are accessing a pointer that has never been assigned to a `new` object.  I would check the locations where you are using playerMonster and make sure that it is valid.  A good way to check is when you fist declare playerMonster set it equal to `nullptr`

```
AbstractMonster* playerMonster = nullptr;
```

Then in the places you use it run a check to see if its still null `if (plasyerMonster == nullptr)`.

Comment: no luck with the null ptr

Comment: @FraserS Enable break on Access Violations in your debugger. Then when it stops backtrack up the callstack to see the line of code in your program that causes the access violation.

Comment: havn't had luck with adding the nullptr. hadnt included enough information

Comment: @drescherjm Ok I've done that and it says line 54 which is the line i stated above. I placed a watch on playerMonster and i get  <Unable to read memory> for its value. any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe mainGame is null there.

Comment: @drescherjm I dont follow what you mean there

Comment: My guess is that your mainGame object is null when you are trying to execute createMonster(). This situation will not cause a crash until you try to use playerMonster or any other non static class member variable.

Comment: Either that or Champion() causes a null pointer access in its constructor.

Comment: @drescherjm the class itself doesn't have a constructor as everything is declared with my own default values.

Comment: Then verify that mainGame is not null. Possibly put a breakpoint at line 54 and look at the this pointer.

Comment: @drescherjm ok looked at it and its null

Comment: @drescherjm solved the issue, changed the way mainGame was initiated